# Duda sobre Diseño de Formulario

Tags: html, bootstrap

el día de hoy tengo una duda sobre el diseño de un formulario que estoy haciendo. Estoy diseñando en Angular, un formulario en **HTML** y **Bootstrap**, solo que *"Tag"* y requerido no están acomodados como *"ID Remedy"* y *"Formulario"*. Por ello les pido su ayuda para dar arreglo solo a ese único detalle. Envió una imagen del formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el código con el que estoy trabajando:

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <label for="tag" class="col-form-label">Tag</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input formControlName="tag" placeholder="Ingrese un tag" name="tag" type="text" class="form-control" id="tag" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <label for="id_remedy" class="col-form-label">ID Remedy</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input formControlName="id_remedy" class="form-control" type="text" name="id_remedy" placeholder="Ingrese el ID Remedy">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <label for="formulario" class="col-form-label">Formulario</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select formControlName="formulario" class="form-control" name="formulario">
          <option value="WL">WL</option>
          <option value="HELP">HELP</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 everything-checkbox">

<div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
    <label for="formulario" class="col-form-label">
        <span>Requerido</span>
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="requerido" name="requerido" value="C" checked/>
        C
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="requerido" name="requerido" value="U"/>
        U
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="requerido" name="requerido" value="A"/>
        A
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: hay un par de div sin cerrar?

Comment: Ah es que lo tengo dentro de un "card" pero este no lo añadí, copie unos div de mas supongo...

Comment: Pone exactamente tu view, o un ejemplo identico que replique tu problema. Si no, vas a recibir respuestas que no van a solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias hacer algo asi:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>EJEMPLO</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="tag" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">TAG</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag" placeholder="Ingrese el tag">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="id_remedy" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">ID Remedy</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_remedy" placeholder="ID Remedy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="id_remedy" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Formulario</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select name="formulario" id="formulario" class="form-control">
          <option value="WL">WL</option>
          <option value="HELP">HELP</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Requerido</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="requerido">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="requerido">
         C
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="requerido">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="requerido">
         U
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="requerido">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="requerido">
         A
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>




    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como ves es algo basico de bootstrap, para mayor referencia te sugiero revisar la documentacion:

[form Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#form-groups)
Espero te sirva y guie..!!

Comment: Hola Diego, se me olvido poner que tanto el texto como los campos (input, checkbox y select) no estén separados, ¿no se si me entiendas?....

Comment: a que te refieres con separados ?

Comment: te sugiero revisar la parte de los formularios en bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/